# CheckBox get value off/on with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

```
<div class="column val" th:each="nameApp,iStat:${listAppName}">
     <div >
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small"  class="Checkbox"><!--checked-->
            <label><span th:text="${nameApp.application_name}"></span></label>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is my html and when I click on check on this show only On

```
$(".val").click(function(){
    var checkedValue = $('.Checkbox:checked').val();
    console.log(checkedValue);
            
});
```

I want only when I tick on checkbox if show On and when I don't tick on checkbox if show off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using  jQuery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

You also need to use `this` keyword to indicate the currently clicked check box.

**Demo:**

```js
$(".val").click(function(){
  //also need to use `this` keyword to indicate the currently cliked check box.
  var checkedValue = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(":checked")? 'On' : 'Off';
  console.log(checkedValue);            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column val" th:each="nameApp,iStat:${listAppName}">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small"  class="Checkbox"><!--checked-->
    <label><span th:text="${nameApp.application_name}"></span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is work for me when I click OFF to ON   but when I have ON to OFF this one don't work is show only ON ON ON ON

Comment: @MangoPlay,though no such issue found in the above answer, I have updated the answer. Please check.